# How can we render mathjax equation in web browser control?

Tags: c#, mathjax

We are using mathjax equations in our document but concern is to render these equations on server side instead of client side. For the rectification of this issue we want to render them in web browser controls. So how can we render mathjax equation in web browser control using c#?

It would be great for us if someone give us any idea about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a very good way to render mathjax equations on the server by using Latex. Latex makes images for the equations and allows you different image formats.

```
var val="your_equation_val";
```

val = "http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?" + val + "\"/>";

Now we have an HTML tag with mathjax equation image finally.